# Probability/selection problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

Assume that we have $N$ items of $M$ distinct types in a closed bag. We also have $K$ bowls $(K \leq M)$ that can hold only items of same type. In the beginning bowls are empty. And bowls can hold a maximum of $P$ items.

We pick items from the bag one-by-one without putting back into the bag. As we pick items, we first look at the bowls if there exists a bowl to hold the picked item (i.e., a bowl with items in it with the same type of the picked item). If we find such a bowl and if the bowl has more space to hold the current item, we simply put the item into that bowl and proceed.

Otherwise, if there is an empty bowl, we place the current item in it and proceed.

Otherwise, we randomly pick a bowl out of $K$ bowls and move all items in it to some reserved space (details doesn't matter here). After that we place the current item in that empty bowl and proceed. Let's call this a replacement.

Now the question is given $N, M, K$ and $P$, what is the expected number of replacements?